# Синхронизация данных в коллекциях

Tags: c#, .net, коллекции

Здравствуйте.

Есть на клиентской стороне тип `List<UserResources>`, содержащий ресурсы пользователя (полученные с сервера).

Раньше получение происходило так:

```
UserResources = Deserialize<UserResource>(Responce.Data);
```

т.е. тупо была замена данных.

Теперь я хочу, чтобы не замена была, а Union. Понял, что для каждого типа нужно делать `EqualityComparer`, и думал, что это нормально. Пока не заметил, что Union объединяет данные, и не удаляет те, которые удалились в бд. Как мне лучше сделать?

Хочу так:

```
UserResources.AddOrDeleteOrUpdate(Deserialize<UserResource>(userPlanetResources));
UserResources.AddOrDeleteOrUpdate(Deserialize<UserResource>(userOrbitResources));
```

Нужно реализовать метод AddOrDeleteOfUpdate

P.S. И как сделать безопасный доступ к `UserResources` из других потоков, чтобы не было проблем, когда обновляются данные и когда забираются?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По поводу второй части вопроса, вам просто нужен `lock` или пересмотреть архитектуру.

По поводу первой части — у вас недостаточно данных. Рассмотрим такую ситуацию: на клиенте есть элементы `[1, 2, 3]`, с сервера приходит список `[1, 2]`. Раз с сервера не передаётся список удалённых из базу элементов, то вы не знаете, элемент 3 удалён на сервере (и его надо удалить и на клиенте), или элемент 3 просто добавлен на клиенте.

Вы можете решить проблему, если будете хранить список элементов на клиенте, которые были добавлены, и отдельно список элементов, которые получены с сервера. При этом серверный список нужно заменить на обновлённые данные с сервера, и несброшенные на сервер новые элементы при этом не будут затронуты.

Answer (score -1):

Использвать конструкцию `lock` https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/c5kehkcz.aspx , если хотите синхронизацию в разрезе приложения, если в разрезе пользователя то тут можно будет использовать данный метод -

```
public static ConcurrentDictionary<string,object> _userLocks = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, object>();

lock(_userLocks.GetOrAdd(userid, x => new object())
{
  // Какие то действия
}
```